# Sharing a link -vs- sharing a link in order to earn the publicist badge

Tags: support

I was asked to share the following link to earn the publicist badge:
 security.stackexchange.com/q/2558/396

My question other than through the random pop-up, how would I get this special url with a prepended "/396" which seems to be treated uniquely within the SE world?

Pardon my lack of proper lingo in this question; I'm not sure what to call these special links, or when an how they are used in the SE sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice, just under the question tags, there is a "`link`" link.
Right click that, and copy the link.

The "/396" is your user id, so it identifies who shared the link.

FYI, this can work with answers too, but you have to create the link yourself - the "`link`" link uses the regular, full path.
E.g. [Sharing a link -vs- sharing a link in order to earn the publicist badge](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/218/33#219)